# How to set the SurfaceView over of ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, opengl-es

I want to set the SurfaceView over the ImageView. I used the below code and layout. It set the surface view over the imageview but It set the surfaceview to top of all views.

Is there any other way to set the SurfaceView over the ImageView.

Please help me.

Code :

```
setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
setZOrderOnTop(true);
```

Layout

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/topFrameLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <!-- ImageView for the product -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photoImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.amplimesh.renderer.RendererView
        android:id="@+id/renderer_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add

```
gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0);
```

in your renderer to ensure the background is transparent.

Comment: I set this even it showing black color. So imageview behind the GLSurfaceview is not visible. Please help me how can i make the imageview visible